# Call signature with generic arguments and return type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to extend a generic `Promise` with a `description` property.

I have the following code:

```js
type DescribableFunction<T extends (...args: any) => any> = {
  (...args: Parameters<T>): Promise<ReturnType<T>>
  description: string
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction<(a: number, b: string) => boolean>) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6,"6").then(console.log))
}

function makeDescriptibleFun<T extends (...args: any) => any>(desc: string, promise: (...args: Parameters<T>) => Promise<ReturnType<T>>): DescribableFunction<T> {

  const p = async (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
    return await promise(...args)
  }

  return Object.assign(p, {description: desc})
}

const a = makeDescriptibleFun("valid", (a: number, b: string) => Promise.resolve(true))
const b = makeDescriptibleFun("invalid", (a: number) => Promise.resolve(false))

doSomething(a)
doSomething(b)
```

output:

```
[LOG]: "valid returned [object Promise]" 
[LOG]: "invalid returned [object Promise]" 
[LOG]: true 
[LOG]: false
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSwEYEN0BsIDEBXAO0WFQHtiAeAFSggA9gJiATeKACgDo-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)

However, I was expecting that `doSomething(b)` would give a compile error since `doSomething` takes a function with two arguments and the function `b` only has one argument?

The same issue occurs without of the notion of `Promise`:

```js
type DescribableFunction<T extends (...args: any) => any> = {
  (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>
  description: string
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction<(a: number, b: string) => boolean>) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6,"6"))
}

function makeDescriptibleFun<T extends (...args: any) => any>(desc: string, promise: (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>): DescribableFunction<T> {

  const p = (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
    return promise(...args)
  }

  return Object.assign(p, {description: desc})
}

const a: DescribableFunction<(a: number, b: string) => boolean> = makeDescriptibleFun("valid", (a: number, b: string) => true)
const b: DescribableFunction<(a: number) => boolean> = makeDescriptibleFun("invalid", (a: number) => false)

doSomething(a)
doSomething(b)
```

I am expecting `doSomething(b)` to give some error since the type `DescribableFunction<(a: number) => boolean>` does not equal the correct type `DescribableFunction<(a: number, b: string) => boolean>`

Comment: See [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) and [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters); does that fully address the question?  If not, what's missing?

Comment: this is not entirely due to the number of arguments, I have tried changing the return type and argument type but I still get no error in the first example. However the second example does give an error with the `DescribableFunction<(a: string) => boolean>` type.

Comment: Ok nvm, this seems to be because I am using `Promise.resolve(true)` instead of `new Promise(() => true)` to create the promise stored in `b`.

Comment: Note that your generic type arguments will never be inferred properly because TS can't infer from conditional types that way; you'd want to change to [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/NaR2Pm), but the underlying issue is the issue highlighted in the docs/faq.  Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Thanks, the type inference seems to downplay when using the function type directly instead of providing the arguments and return type as separate generic types as you showed there. I wanted to avoid this because I though it was cleaner to write `DescribableFunction<(a: number, b: string) => boolean>` instead of `DescribableFunction<[a: number, b: string], boolean>`. But the function type approach would require explictly setting the type for `b` [like this](https://tsplay.dev/NDgyxw).